# gcloud auth application-default print-access-token gives file not found error

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently trying to set up a service account to run a google cloud vision OCR sample but for some reason the `print-access-token` command keeps failing to find my key. I've completed the following steps 3 times already just to make sure I've followed the exact steps in the docs:

1. Init gcloud SDK with project i had already created
2. Enabled billing
3. Create a JSON file containing key for service account with project owner as its role
4. `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\path\to\file\file.json"`
5. run gcloud auth application-default print-access-token

I've also tried using `gcloud auth application-default login` just to be safe as it seemed to work for others who had different issues with print access token, but still no luck.

This is the error i receive from using print-access-token

```
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.print-access-token) File "C:\path\file.json" was not found.
```

I've tried running the the code samples regardless of this and receive the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the vision.googleapis.com.
```

I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere. I understand it might be a stupid problem with an easy fix, but I'm really quite confused at the moment because I'm sure I've done everything fine so far. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: are you in free trial?

Comment: I don't think so? When i was creating my GCP account i didnt see anything about free trial, only about usage quotas. I have my billing account set up if that provides any insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received the message about the file `was not found`, but I fixed this by using the command `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` without double quotation marks for example

*I recommend use paths without spaces or special characters, for example `C:\creds\cred1.json`*

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=C:\path\to\file\file.json
```

*this environment variable only applies for the current CMD window is not system wide environment variable*

The command `gcloud auth application-default login` creates a system wide credential based on an user account that allows test some APIs, but for others like `vision` it is necessary to use service account credentials

To fix this issue you need to define the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as [user session or system wide environment variable](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

After this step, your code going to recognize the credentials stored on the environment variable`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` in this case `C:\path\to\file\file.json`

Comment: This worked, thanks! I set the environment variable manually and print-access-token is working now!